# Join a list that is full with tuples and not string

Tags: python

I wish to join a list of tuples to form a string.

```
l = [(2,3), (3,5), (4,5)]
print(" ".join(l))
```

My error:

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

My expectation:

(2,3) (3,5) (4,5) #I only know how to join for string and I thought it will be simple until I found this. Please kindly assist me.

Comment: the error message is there to help you. It's stating that `join` expects strings. Just convert the tuples to strings before joining them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to cast the tuples to a string, you can do it by using map:

```py
l = [(2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
print(" ".join(map(str, l)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much and I also just realized too.

Comment: Hi, I am wondering whether will it be possible to make the output like this? (23) (3 5) (4 5). The comma replaces with space

Comment: of course, just use .replace: `print(" ".join(map(str, l)).replace(",", ""))`

Comment: Thank you so much. I didnt realize at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> l = [(2,3), (3,5), (4,5)]
>>> " ".join([str(i) for i in l])
'(2, 3) (3, 5) (4, 5)'
```

Comment: Hi, I am wondering whether will it be possible to make the output like this? (23) (3 5) (4 5). The comma replaces with space

Comment: @Anonymous Instead of `str(i)` use `str(i). replace (',', ' ')`. This will do your job.